# A Basic understanding of Operators and Eigen-stuff

Tags: quantum-mechanics, eigenvalue

I'm currently taking an intro quantum theory course and I'm missing something fundamental about eigen-stuff.

If you have an observable operator, O, to my understanding, by virtue of its observability it is self adjoint and therefore has an Eigenbasis. We can tell this is the case if O|a> = @|a> (where @ is # which is the scalar multiplication coefficient, also known as its eigenvalue and |a> is its eigenvector). I think I'm missing the true meaning of the eigen-part where is the eigenvalue pointing it to, what vector are we mapping? The problem I'm being posed on my worksheet is to find the possible outcomes (eigenbasis right?) of the observable operator O (O|α> = 7|α> and O|β> = 8|β>) how do we use the eigenvectors and eigenvalues given to find the eigenbasis?

I'm also asked to find the inner product of the vectors α and β so (<α|β>) I have a guess but I'm not sure at all: |α> = 1 x |α> + 0 x|β> and |β> = 0 x |α> + 1 x|β> Therefore <α|β>= (1 x 0) + (0 x 1)= 0. Just looking for some feedback and maybe how if at all, this inner product is related to the eigen stuff above.

Thank you in advance its super appreciated, I'm interested by this stuff and really dont want to drop the class so more than getting the homework done (thats important too ) I want to understand what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1):

In general, an operator (in its simplest form: a matrix) transforms a vector to another vector or, to borrow part of your language, maps $\vert a\rangle$ to another vector $\vert b\rangle$.

*On occasions*, the vector $\vert b\rangle$ is just a multiple $\lambda$ of the original vector $\vert a\rangle$, i.e. it sometime happen that, if you choose "the right" $\vert a\rangle$, $\vert b\rangle=\lambda\vert a\rangle$.  Given an operator, this will occur only for some very specific $\vert a\rangle$ (at most as many vectors as the dimension of the space).  The value $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of the operator and the $\vert a\rangle$ is the eigenvector.

By the postulates of QM, the eigenvalues of an operator are the possible outcomes of measuring this operator.  Note that it is typically easier to find the eigenvalues than the eigenvectors, in the sense that the eigenvalues are the roots of a determinental equation, which can be solved without knowledge of the eigenvectors.  If an eigenvalue occurs once, the corresponding eigenvector is unique (up to a phase and normalization).  If an eigenvalue occurs more than once, the linear combinations of eigenvectors with this eigenvalue are also eigenvectors; this is not the situation of your problem where the eigenvalues are distinct, so I will not dive into the complication of repeated eigenvalues.

Because physically measurable quantities are real, the eigenvalues of an operator that describes a physical quantity must be real.  This is guaranteed if the operator is self-adjoint, and so physical quantities are usually represented by self-adjoint operators.

It is then an easy theorem to show that two eigenvectors of the same operators that have distinct eigenvalues must be orthogonal; your conclusion is correct but you should look up a proof of this important property of eigenvectors of self-adjoint operators.

Comment: I just want to clarify that in the problem given the possible outcomes (eigenbasis) of the operator are just 7 and 8 (its eigenvalues) ? This seems too simple, or rather silly that I was that confused about something this simple.

Comment: The possible outcomes are the eigenvalues, not the eigenbasis.

Comment: But arent all of the possible eigenvalues for an observable called its eigenbasis? I just have that halfway scrawled in my notes want to amend it if its wrong.

Comment: no.  the eigenbasis is the basis of eigenvectors.  Eigenvalues are numbers; they are not vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a theorem in this case (Hermitian operator) that eigenstates of distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal?

The phrasing of "find the possible outcomes of the observable operator" is a bit confusing. I think maybe it meant "possible outcomes of the observable", which is just code for all the eigenvalues. The eigenvalues of the Hermitian operator corresponding to the observable is what you measure/observe when you try to make a measurement that observable.

Comment: In finite dimensional cases there is no distinction between hermitian and self-adjoint.  There are subtleties associated with domains in the infinite-dimensional case, and hermitian is not necessarily self-adjoint.  Strictly speaking, the theorem is valid for self-adjoint operators.